# How to create a sub-category for a corpus in NLTK Python

Tags: python, nltk, corpus

I was trying to create another category under a parent category.
Is is possible to create. How it can be done and how can a refer to these sub-categories?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to categorize a corpus is to have one file for each category. Following are two excerpts from the movie_reviews corpus:

`movie_pos.txt`

`the thin red line is flawed but it provokes .`

`movie_neg.txt`

`a big-budget and glossy production can not make up for a lack of
   spontaneity that permeates their tv show .`

With these two files, we'll have two categories: pos and neg.

We'll use the `CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader`, which inherits from both `PlaintextCorpusReader` and `CategorizedCorpusReader`. These two superclasses require three arguments: the root directory, the `fileids`, and a category specification.

```
>>> from nltk.corpus.reader import 
CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader
>>> reader = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader('.', r'movie_.*\.
txt', cat_pattern=r'movie_(\w+)\.txt')
>>> reader.categories()
['neg', 'pos']
>>> reader.fileids(categories=['neg'])
['movie_neg.txt']
>>> reader.fileids(categories=['pos'])
['movie_pos.txt']
```

The first two arguments to `CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader` are the root directory and fileids, which are passed on to the PlaintextCorpusReader to read n the files. The `cat_pattern` keyword argument is a regular expression for extracting the category names from the fileids. In our case, the category is the part of the fileid after movie_ and before .txt. The category must be surrounded by grouping parenthesis. cat_pattern is passed to `CategorizedCorpusReader`, which overrides the common corpus reader functions such as `fileids()`, `words()`, `sents()`, and `paras()` to accept a categories keyword argument. This way, you could get all the pos sentences by calling `reader.sents(categories=['pos'])`. `CategorizedCorpusReader` also provides the categories() function, which returns a list of all known categories in the corpus.

Answer (score 1):

`CategorizedCorpusReader` only supports one level of categories. But since categories are based on the filename, you are free to set up your own name/category scheme and filter the corpus fileids as needed.

How do you want to use the multi-level categories? If you have follow-up questions, explain what you want to achieve and what you have tried so far.